# MouseUp event firing wrong

Tags: c#, wpf

The MouseUp event on my Image control gets fired wrong, it get's fired at the same time as my MouseUp event on the Window..

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Is the `image` variable a container and set to stretch? If so you might indeed be over that stretched control despite only seeing the image in the upper left corner. To figure out if that is the case, don't do the `DragMove` and just click on that spot to see if you receive the event there.

Comment: I would assume it is logical that `IsMouseOver` is `true`, if it wasn't, the event would not have fired in the first place. Can you produce please a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer to my problem..

By using a Buttons click event and just change the style..

The reason for the Image.MouseUp event was fired was, because it was somehow connected to the Window.MouseUp event..

Answer (score 0):

Hard to be sure without seeing your XAML, but this is almost certainly going to be down to your image having a clickable area covering the whole window.

Set up a grid and place the image in the top-left corner ensuring the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment properties are both set to 'Stretch'.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="Image" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
           Source="http://www.whitegadget.com/attachments/pc-wallpapers/110295d1340346189-nina-dobrev-nina-dobrev-iomage.jpg"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: As you can see below, the event will only fire when you drag over the actual image]

Comment: Have you tried the grid approach with properly set parameters like I've shown in the example?

Comment: Yes I have.  What are you trying to say - is the code I put not working in the way you expect?

Comment: It is *not* activated with the code I posted.  You should try it.  I cannot run your code since it doesn't even compile.  Please run the code I gave you and tell me if it exhibits the problem.

Comment: Ok I've run your code and Image.MouseUp does *not* fire when dragging the window around.  I'd suggest posting a different question if this is not the problem.